# Spark cluster submission can't bind to slave address

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

```
ERROR netty.NettyTransport: failed to bind to spark.master/172.28.128.3:0, shutting down Netty transport
15/03/16 04:08:50 WARN util.Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
```

That ^^^ is the error that I'm getting from my slave log. I'm submitting my job with spark-submit. This makes no sense since the slaves are able to connect to the master as shown in the web-ui. I thought I've configured the correct ports as shown bellow are my configurations on all machines.

Spark-Env.sh

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=$(ip addr  | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d'/')
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=spark.master
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=9919
```

Spark-Defaults.Conf

```
spark.master                        spark://spark.master:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled              true
spark.eventLog.dir                  hdfs://spark.master:8020/spark-log
spark.yarn.submit.file.replication  3
spark.app.name                      quant
spark.ui.port                       4040
spark.driver.port                   9929
spark.executor.port                 9939
spark.driver.host                   spark.slave
```

This on my slave and master nodes. When I submit a job, I'm using the bash command =>

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --class dev.quant.App --deploy-mode cluster hdfs:///spark/my-app.jar
```

spark-env.sh and spark-defaults.conf are chmod 775 so they should be running.

The log from my master is:

```
15/03/16 04:08:51 INFO master.Master: Removing driver: driver-20150316040848-0002
15/03/16 04:08:54 INFO master.Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@spark.master:55303 got disassociated, removing it.
15/03/16 04:08:54 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://driverClient@spark.master:55303] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/03/16 04:08:54 INFO master.Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@spark.master:55303 got disassociated, removing it.
15/03/16 04:08:54 INFO actor.LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkMaster/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkMaster/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkMaster%40172.28.128.3%3A32995-5#678153583] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

From what I heard, launching in cluster mode is not supported, which makes no sense to me since standalone spark is supposed to be a cluster solution. So I've also tried launching in client mode which gives me ClassNotFoundException: dev.quant.App which makes no sense to me since my jar clearly has it + all dependencies are packed together as denoted in the assembly. I've been trying to get this stupid thing set up for too long and it would be nice to have a break. Lastly I have scala 2.10.5 installed and my app is packaged with 2.10.5 if that matters.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot what I did, if you're having this issue, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Yes I've got it, it would help if you can recall what what wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

spark.driver.host looks suspicious to me. I think it should be set to spark.master and not spark.slave. Or just remove that parameter completely.